How can I remove a T7 bulb broken off close to end in the fixture?
The bulb R7 broke off in the fixture, close to the end. How do I remove it?

Which do you have a T7 or an R7  your post mentions both.

I put the "T7" back in the title, since RMDan's comment and answer wouldn't fit anymore. FWIW "R7" could be a fat finger, as R & T are next to each other on some keyboards.

In any case be sure the electric is off to the fixture.  If a T7 bulb, use needle nose pliers to grip the edge of the base and turn counter-clockwise.
If you have an R7 bulb it is unclear how it could be stuck.

Electric off should be done at the breaker, especially if using fingers and/or metal tools that close to power.  Switches alone are not trustfully.

Seconding @crip659 here - I've seen too many times where someone decided to switch the neutral, not hot. Turns the light off just fine, but is a real hazard to anyone working on the light.

My post did state. " Be sure the electric is off."  NOT turn off the switch.  In any average home in america you switch off a light at a wall switch or a lamp switch. Turning off the hot.   Why would anyone suspect that someone, at sometime, may have switched hot and neutral and possibly wire a light that way?  Could it happen?   Yes. However assuming this is like assuming that when you put your car in drive that it may go in reverse because someone may have reversed the gears or changed the shifting mechanism.  It could happen!  You are assuming far too much.

"be sure the electric is off" does cover all bases. FWIW I have lived in an apartment where every outlet had power and neutral reversed. The Juicy side was the wide side. Folks do weird things with electricity sometimes. A warning to cut power at the breaker or confirmedly unplug the lamp would make the warning more clear for this 'need to have everything explained because there's no common sense anymore' world.  That said, I upvoted. Nice answer!

I have seen people do odd things like shoving a potato against the lamp base and using that to turn it. For multiple reasons, I really don't recommend that, but I thought I'd mention it as a possible desperation move. Do still turn the power off first, since the potato is not a good insulator.

Don't they make electricity from potatoes?
